# Cascading delete with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a comments table which contains amongst other things the columns `Id` - the ID of the comment, `Commenter_Id` the ID of the user who posted it, and `ParentComment_Id` a self referencing foreign key. There are only two levels to the commenting, parents and sub comments. If a comment record has a `ParentComment_Id` of null, then it is a parent comment.

I'm trying to write an expression to delete all the comments for a user, but this is causing problems because of that self reference I mentioned earlier.

Take this records sample as an example of the problem:

[image]

User with ID 2 posted a comment, with an ID of 3. Because this was the parent comment it has a `ParentComment_Id` value of null. Later on, User with ID 1 responds to that comment with a sub-comment, creating comment 7 (there were other comments/subcomments between these two hence the Id increment jump).

I'm not able to delete Comment ID 3 because the sub comment, Comment ID 7, has a foreign key to it.

Currently my Entity Framework statement for trying to delete comments is as follows:

```
context.Comments.Where(x => x.Commenter.Id == user.Id).Delete();
```

But this gives me an exception because of the described problem.

I could probably fix this using a few foreach loops, but I was hoping there is an easier way like `context.Cascade().Where(...`. For those wondering the `Delete()` method is part of the EntityFramework.Extended package.

Comment: If a comment is deleted, do you want all the child comments to be deleted as well, or do you want their ParentComment_Id sent to null?

Comment: I want to delete all the child comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an entity like this:

```
public class Comment
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int? ParentCommentId{get;set;}

  public virtual Comment ParentComment{get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments{get;set;}
}
```

You could try with this configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
                .HasOptional(c=>c.ParentComment)
                .WithMany(c=>c.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCommentId) 
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

You can configure cascade delete on a relationship by using the `WillCascadeOnDelete` method.If a foreign key on the dependent entity *is nullable*, Code First *does not set cascade delete on the relationship*, and when the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this to your dbcontext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comments>()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentCommentId) 
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: This seems good, is there a way to set all entities to cascade without repeating the statement n times?

Comment: You might be able to add modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>()
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(). Haven't tried it though.

Comment: I'm doing this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);` with a DbSet of `public DbSet<Comment> Comments{ get; set; }` however it's not finding your WillCascadeOnDelete. I'm on EF 6