# Entity Framework: Automatic deletion of m-end in 1:m relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a MSSQL-database with two tables with a 1:m relation.

I would like the m-end to be deleted automatically when the last corresponding 1-end is deleted.
Is there a possibility to tell EF to automatically remove the row on the m-side once the last referring row on the 1-side is deleted?

I use EF 6.0.

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607704/cascading-delete-with-entity-framework

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. So far I understand that post basically adds a delete cascade programmatically. I want that delete cascade too but it should be fired only when the last referring row is deleted. I assume I need to program this manually...

Comment: I think you are mixing up 1-end and m-end in your question. I don't see any way of doing what you want except doing this manually.

Comment: No, I don't mix them up. But I as well assume that this is only manually possible. I haven't found anything like this on the internet yet.